# ADB - how does it work?

Tags: java, android, service, adb

it's clear to me that one can use ADB to run commands on connected Android device, but how does it work internally?
My assumption is that after for instance calling 'adb shell' ADB connects with some internal service running on Android device or emulator and communicates with it.
What I want to do is to connect to this service which parses ADB commands directly from device (assuming it's not connected to PC) and run ADB commands directly from device. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I know. Rooted phones can have a terminal emulator on the, but that ties directly into the phone, rather than going through the adb daemon. Depending on what you want to do, you might still be able to use the terminal emulator on a rooted phone. Check this post out: http://androidforums.com/eris-all-things-root/109607-terminal-emulators-adb-question.html

Answer (score 2):

ADB is a deamon running at the native layer.  It is started when the phone is started in init.rc, Androids version of init.c.  ADB can take commands in Androids shell scripting language which is similar yet different to BASH.